# Send emails to members week before expiry

Tags: php, sql

I am build an app in php that sends an automatic email (using a cron job) to clients a week before their membership expires. Is there a way to just retrieve records from my database that are at least a week before expiring?

I have done this:

```
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));

$query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, renewal_date, membership_id FROM v_clients_members WHERE renewal_date < '$today'";
```

then tried to refine it with

```
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")+"1 week");

$query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, renewal_date, membership_id FROM v_clients_members WHERE renewal_date < '$today'";
```

I know my issue is the declaration of the $today but I have no clue on how to get today's date + a week.

PS
I know I should used prepared statements but its legacy code a clients wants me to use despite my objections. Also using a cron job because I will probably set it up so that every morning (2 - 3am) it does the database check and sends the emails.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any search effort.  Before asking questions, you should look for it online.  You may also want to read the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to make sure that the question fits all guidelines.

Comment: You can do this in MySQL - have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you know that `date("Y-m-d")+"1 week"` doesn't make much sense, and that you used it to show us what you meant, so I won't go into further details there.

Anyway, `strtotime()` expects the first argument to (according to he PHP-manual) be a:

> string to parse, according to the GNU Date Input Formats syntax

If you check out [this document about relative date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), you can see:

> number space? - Handles relative time items where the value is a number.

This means that you can use `1 week` to define a date that is 1 week from now on.

```
$expire = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("1 week"));
$query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, renewal_date, membership_id FROM v_clients_members WHERE renewal_date < '$expire'";
```